# Stream radio on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I'm developing internet radio using android MediaPlayer. I need to update UI when the song is over and new song begins. How to find, that song is over?
This is my current code. mMediaPlayer.start(); calls when user tap the button.

```
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamURL);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio streaming is endless so the streaming is never going to end, however if what you can do is track the metadata in the radio streaming for the currently playing song, and if you detect that something has changed, then do something.
Something more important that I want to point is that `MediaPlayer` is awful slow for radio streaming, I developed a [radio streaming app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arzion.streame) myself so I strongly reccomend you to use this [library](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer) for this, for two reasons, one is faster and has a bigger buffer than the `MediaPlayer` (`MediaPlayer` class has at some point a hardcoded `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];` buffer that'll bring you some issues) and second because this library lets you handle the metadata in a more confortable way.

Comment: Thanks. FFMpeg was my second option if I couldn't find the solution with MediaPlayer.

Comment: Can you help me with FFMpeg? I use precompiled libs and fmp.jar to create MediaPlayer. I added .jar as library and copied .so files to libs folder. Everything compiles, but app crash on `FFmpegMediaPlayer mp = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();`. App can't find .so files, but they in libs folder.